# getting shapes from an array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, arduino, arduino-esp32

I have a 2d array of zeros and ones, and I want to know the shape that the ones create.

For example this array - will be a rectangle:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I made this array, and I don't know where/which machine learning model should i use.

```
for (int pins = 0; pins < 6; pins++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        if (analogRead(inputs[y]) > 300) {
            Data[pins][y] = 1;
        }
        else {
            Data[pins][y] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I had an idea of transforming the array to an image and using image detection model but i don't know how to do that either.

(I'm using Arduino IDE with an ESP32 connected)

Comment: Please add the tag for the language you're using (this looks like C, but please confirm)

Comment: Your question is quite vague: The shape above could also be an ellipse. Are you only looking for symmetrical shapes (circle, square) or also more elaborate such as star, ellipse, rectangle, irregular triangles? Will the object be rotated?

Comment: @mgb I am only looking for rectangles, triangles, and circles.
All of the objects from the same class will be the same.
The objects could be rotated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what you are looking for is the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull):
[image]

If so, check the examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-using-graham-scan/) to learn how to calculate it. You can use the number of vertexes to realize if the object is a triangle, a square or a circle.

Just in case you are new to Stackoverflow, take a look at the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

The Convex Hull algorithm suggested by @Duloren would work with some additional post-processing:

You could to detect number of "long sides" (maybe sides longer than 30% of the size of the shape). For 3 "long sides" it would be a triangle, for 2 perpendicular sets of parallel "long sides" pairs it would be a rectangle. In the example given by @Duloren convex hull would return 3 long sides, the line at the top, the line at the right and the diagonal at the bottom left so it would be a triangle.

You might also have to combine almost parallel sides to "long sides". For example if the top blue line in Duloren's image was tilted down on the right, the two rightmost points of the top row would not part of the shape. In that case the top "long side" would be split in two lines at a 26deg angle of length 3 and 2.2(=sqrt(5)).

To detect a rectangle you would also have to allow some error how parallel and perpendicular the sides would need to be.

If the result from convex hull doesn't have any "long sides" the shape might be a circle. To test for that you could calculate the center of mass of all the points returned by Convex Hull. If all these points have a similar distance from the center of mass it would be a circle.

Otherwise the shape would be unclassified (not a circle, not a triangle, not a rectangle).